# edit field based on role in crm2011 in javascript code

Tags: http, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Anybody know that, how can write a javascript code in crm2011 to give edit option in one field based on security role?

Comment: my field name is case title  and also have some dropdown option in this field , and my role name is case title edit

Comment: Can you use field level security? https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamics101trainingcentercrm/archive/2013/09/03/how-to-configure-field-level-security-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to check the user roles on form load & enable the field. Make the field read-only by default.

Note: It has dependency to use jQuery & Json scripts to be loaded before this script library.

```
//Check login User has 'case title edit' role
function CheckUserRole() {
    var currentUserRoles = Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentUserRoles.length; i++) {
         var userRoleId = currentUserRoles[i];
    var userRoleName = GetRoleName(userRoleId);
        if (userRoleName == "case title edit") {

//make the field editable here...
 Xrm.Page.getControl("fieldname").setDisabled(false); 

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Get Rolename based on RoleId
function GetRoleName(roleId) {
    //var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    var serverUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName();
    var odataSelect = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc" + "/" + "RoleSet?$filter=RoleId eq guid'" + roleId + "'";
    var roleName = null;
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: odataSelect,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                roleName = data.d.results[0].Name;
            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('OData Select Failed: ' + textStatus + errorThrown + odataSelect); }
        }
    );
    return roleName;
}
```

[Reference](https://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/get-login-user-role-names-in-javascript-in-dynamics-crm-2011/)